# VS 2012 and windows 2008 Server Enterprise

Tags: visual-studio, windows-server-2008

When I try to install Visual Studio 2012 on Windows Server 2008 Enterprise, I have  a error message from installer.

```
  You must upgrade or update Operating Systems to the latest Service Pack using Window Update to meet the requirement before installing this products.
  For Windows 8, this product is not compatible with pre-released versions of Windows 8. Please upgrade to latest release version of Windows 8.
  This computer does not meet the setup requirements. For more information, see the readme.
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=255962
```

I  already installed  every update on  Operating system.
What have I do to install VS2012 Ultimate ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is clearly stated by Microsoft that only 4 Windows releases are supported by Visual Studio 2012, and Windows Server 2008 (non-R2) is not qualified,

> - Windows 7 SP1 (x86 and x64)
> - Windows 8 (x86 and x64)
> - Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 (x64)
> - Windows Server 2012 (x64)

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-ultimate-2012#product-edition-ultimate-requirements

I believe the link included in the error message can also lead you to this information.

So stop your fight in vain and try to build a qualified machine.

Comment: Today,your link leads to the visual studio homepage that does not state the requirements. This is the updated link that lists the requirements: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34673