# Visual Studio 2012 Premium Compatibility with Windows Server 2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, windows-server-2008, compatibility

At my company we're planning to upgrade from Visual Studio 2008 to Visual Studio 2012 Premium. All our dev computers has Windows Server 2008 Enterprise Edition OS and we have not been able to install properly. Only one box having Windows Server 2008 **R2** was successfully upgraded to VS 2012 Prem but we cannot use that Windows version as per internal company standards.

Is there any upgrade package available to keep current OS configuration and install VS 2012 Prem? Or should we go one step further and upgrade our OS confirguration?

At VisualStudio.com web site does not have a quickly and easy way to check VS compatibility with differentes OSs.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [VS 2012 and windows 2008 Server Enterprise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15263082/vs-2012-and-windows-2008-server-enterprise)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio 2012 supports Windows 7 and newer. Windows Vista is unsupported, as is the server version of Windows Vista (Server 2008).

You will need to upgrade to at least Windows Server 2008r2 or Windows 7 (SP1) to install Visual Studio 2012.

You can build an application that targets Windows Vista or below, but you cannot run Visual Studio 2012 and newer on these operating systems.

Supported Operating System

- Windows 7 SP1 (x86 and x64)
- Windows 8 (x86 and x64)
- Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 (x64)
- Windows Server 2012 (x64)

Source: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30678

Comment: Yeap. We will discuss today the alternative path to upgrade our OS to Win Server 2008 R2 if it is not an issue from standards perspective. Thanks a lot for your response and providing MS documentation.